# Binomial coefficient inequality equation proofs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Prove the statement :
*If n is a positive integer, then*
$$1=\binom{n}{0}<\binom{n}{1}<...<\binom{n}{⌊n/2⌋} = \binom{n}{⌈n/2⌉}>...>\binom{n}{n−1}>\binom{n}{n}=1  $$

I tried to read up the falling/rising factorial notation from internet sources, but I cannot find how to write up the first step.

The options are as follows (We have to put it in the right order, one option is incorrect) :

- If $k<= n / 2$, then $k/(n — k + 1)$, so the "*greater than*" signs are correct. Similarly, if $k>n/ 2$, then $k/(n - k + 1)$, so the "*less than*" signs are correct.
- If $k<= n / 2$, then $k/(n — k + 1)$, so the "*less than*" signs are correct. Similarly, if $k>n/ 2$, then $k/(n - k + 1)$, so the "*greater than*" signs are correct.
- Since $⌊n/2⌋ + ⌈n/2⌉ = n$, the equalities at the ends are clear.
- The equalities at the ends are clear. Using the factorial formulae for computing binomial coefficients, we see that $C(n, k — 1) = (k / (n - k + 1)) C(n, k) $

My understanding so far:
If we consider a sample k as
$$k = 2  ...  k = 5$$ and we consider $$n = 7$$
Then $ \binom{n}{3} = \binom{n}{⌊n/2⌋}$ because the floor value of $n/2$ is $3$
But the same holds good on the right side of the equation with greater than signs with $ \binom{n}{4} = \binom{n}{⌈n/2⌉}$ because the ceiling value of $n/2$ is $4$

It is confusing to understand which of the steps is correct between the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ provided in the option list. Also what is the first step for solving this, the problem definition or something similar does not exist in the text provided.

Comment: Are those the exact statements? "If $k < n/2$, then $k/(n-k+1)$" is not a complete sentence. What happens with that fraction?

Comment: Sir, I have reproduced it verbatim, there is nothing else, the complete line is as such. I will edit it, I just realized its $k <= n/2$

Comment: Sir, After a lot of online videos and reading, I am better understanding that the above inequality is some $(x + y)^n$ .  
If $n = 7$ and the equation was $(x + y)^7$  
We have the following :
$$\binom{7}{0} < \binom{7}{1} < \binom{7}{2} < \binom{7}{3} = \binom{7}{4} ... \binom{7}{0} = 1$$  
if $k < n/2$ , I dont understand this because $k$ goes up to $n/2$ in the above equation , in this case (left hand side) does not go up to 4, due to the fact that we are considering the floor value. On the (rhs) it goes from 4 up to 1 (the coefficient) as we consider the ceiling value.

Comment: Contd: Should we consider the inequality $⌊n/2⌋ <= k <= ⌈n/2⌉$.  
if so, how do we use the options 1 and 2 above. Please help.

Comment: To clarify: The inequalities should be $$1 = \binom{7}{0} < \binom{7}{1} < \binom{7}{2} < \binom{7}{3} = \binom{7}{4} > \binom{7}{5} > \binom{7}{6} > \binom{7}{7} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{split}
\binom{n}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k}&=\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!(k+1)!}-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{n-k}\right)
\end{split}$$
Thus
$$\binom{n}{k+1}\geq\binom{n}{k} \text{ if and only if } k+1 \leq n-k \text{, i.e. } 2k +1\leq n$$

Comment: Sir, thank you very much .Can you please advise if this is the right order of the proof :  

 -  If $k<= n / 2$, then $k/(n — k + 1)$, so the "*less than*" signs are correct. Similarly, if $k>n/ 2$, then $k/(n - k + 1)$, so the "*greater than*" signs are correct.  


 -  Since $⌊n/2⌋ + ⌈n/2⌉ = n$, the equalities at the ends are clear.  


 -  The equalities at the ends are clear. Using the factorial formulae for computing binomial coefficients, we see that $C(n, k — 1) = (k / (n - k + 1)) C(n, k) $

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer wrong. Here is the answer :

Using the factorial formulae for computing binomial coefficients, we see that $C(n, k – 1) = (k/(n – k + 1)) C(n, k)$

If $k ≤ n/2, then , k/(n – k + 1) < 1$, so the "less than" signs are correct. Similarly, if $k > n/2, then , k/(n – k + 1) > 1$, so the "greater than" signs are correct.

Since  $C(n, r)=C(n, n−r)  , we have  C(n,⌊n2⌋)=C(n, n−⌊n2⌋)=C(n,⌈n2⌉)  because  ⌊n2⌋+⌈n2⌉=n$  . Thus, the middle equality is clear.

The equalities at the ends are clear.